# Как изменить картинку на сайте при определенном разрешении?

Tags: javascript, html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Необходимо, чтобы при мобильном разрешении была одна картинка, а при десктопном разрешении - другая. Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: гуглить css media queries

Comment: Что именно за картинка? Фон или img?

Comment: Картинка img,не фон

Answer (score 12):

Медиа-запрос
Допустим, по дефолту имеем `background-image:url("images/main.png");`
И определяем медиа-запрос для девайсов с разрешением от 320 до 500 пикселей:

```
@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:500px) {
    .your-block {
         background-image:url("images/mobile.png");
    }
}
```

Если нужно, чтобы менялась именно содержательная картинка(вставленная с помощью тега `img` в ваш `html` - алгоритм тот же, только у вас должно быть две картинки, допустим одна имеет класс `mobile-img`, вторая соответственно  `main-img`. И получаете что-то вроде вот такого `css`

```
.mobile-img {
    display:none;
}

 @media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:500px) {
    .mobile-img {
         display:block;
    }
    .main-img {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я бы использовал js, чтобы не грузить большие картинки на мобильные

Comment: Можно и так, но это ведь уже вопрос опитимизации)

Answer (score 5):

Смотрите в сторону атрибутов **srcset**, **sizes** у элемента **img** или используйте возможности элемента **picture**. Элемент **picture** имеет более «продвинутые» возможности.

Можно не только изменять (увеличивать или уменьшать) фактический размер картинки при различных плотностях или разрешения экрана устройства, но, например, отобразить вместо альбомной картинки — картинку портретной ориентации, что порой бывает полезно при создании адаптивного/отзывчивого сайта или приложения.

Поддержка браузерами [srcset](https://caniuse.com/#search=srcset) и [picture](https://caniuse.com/#search=picture).

Но там где возможно, например для логотипа, лучше использовать векторный формат изображений — **SVG**. Формат широко [поддерживается](https://caniuse.com/#search=svg) браузерами.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img
        src="200x100.png"
        srcset="300x150.png 1.5x,
                400x200.png 2x,
                600x300.png 3x,
                800x400.png 4x"
        alt="">

        <picture>
            <source media="(min-resolution: 4dppx)" srcset="800x400.png">
            <source media="(min-resolution: 3dppx)" srcset="600x300.png">
            <source media="(min-resolution: 1.5dppx)" srcset="400x200.png">
            <source media="(min-resolution: 1dppx)" srcset="300x150.png">
            <img src="200x100.png" alt="">
        </picture>

        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="800x400.png">
            <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="600x300.png">
            <source media="(min-width: 400px)" srcset="400x200.png">
            <source media="(min-width: 300px)" srcset="300x150.png">
            <img src="200x100.png" alt="">
        </picture>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Тут ведь не адаптивность картинки, а отображение другой.

Comment: А можете добавить запускемый пример?

Comment: В ближайшее время добавлю. Только начал отвечать на Stack Overflow, не совсем механика по началу понятна. Но сейчас в справке посмотрел (раздел «Подсветка синтаксиса в коде») — вроде ничего сложного нет.

Answer (score 3):

Если вдруг картинки `img` и менять разметку никак нельзя, то можно вопрользоваться таким хаком (будет работать только для фиксированных размеров):

```css
.image {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KXRp.jpg");
  /* Устанавливаем ширину и высоту в 0 */
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  /* Устанавливаем размеры за счёт padding-left и padding-top */
  padding-left: 300px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  /* Устанавливаем по своему вкусу, здесь изображение будет растигиваться под размеры блока */
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

/* медиа запросы с другим фоном */
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .image {
      background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OcHP.jpg");    
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KXRp.jpg" />
```